# Typescript complains about missing semicolon on imported json module

Tags: json, typescript, vue.js, npm, webpack

I'm trying to load a local JSON object into my `Vuex` store using `const tree = import('@/articles/tree.json');`. 
I've enabled `"resolveJsonModule": true,` in my `tsconfig.json` it loads fine, but `NPM` spams the output with the warnings such as:

```
WARNING in /home/benjamin/dev/learn-wgpu2/src/articles/tree.json(1,8654):
1:8654 Missing semicolon
```

I think that Webpack is trying to lint the JSON as a Typescript file. How do I get it to stop doing that?

Here is the json file in question.

```
{"path":"src/articles/","name":"articles","display":"","type":"folder","children":[{"path":"src/articles//about.md","name":"about.md","display":"/about.md","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner","name":"beginner","display":"/beginner","type":"folder","children":[{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial1-window","name":"tutorial1-window","display":"/beginner/tutorial1-window","type":"folder","children":[{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial1-window/README.md","name":"README.md","display":"/beginner/tutorial1-window/README.md","type":"file"}]},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial2-swapchain","name":"tutorial2-swapchain","display":"/beginner/tutorial2-swapchain","type":"folder","children":[{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial2-swapchain/README.md","name":"README.md","display":"/beginner/tutorial2-swapchain/README.md","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial2-swapchain/cleared-window.png","name":"cleared-window.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial2-swapchain/cleared-window.png","type":"file"}]},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial3-pipeline","name":"tutorial3-pipeline","display":"/beginner/tutorial3-pipeline","type":"folder","children":[{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/README.md","name":"README.md","display":"/beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/README.md","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/tutorial3-pipeline-composite.svg","name":"tutorial3-pipeline-composite.svg","display":"/beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/tutorial3-pipeline-composite.svg","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/tutorial3-pipeline-triangle.png","name":"tutorial3-pipeline-triangle.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/tutorial3-pipeline-triangle.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/tutorial3-pipeline-vertices.png","name":"tutorial3-pipeline-vertices.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/tutorial3-pipeline-vertices.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/tutorial3-pipeline-vertices.svg","name":"tutorial3-pipeline-vertices.svg","display":"/beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/tutorial3-pipeline-vertices.svg","type":"file"}]},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial4-buffer","name":"tutorial4-buffer","display":"/beginner/tutorial4-buffer","type":"folder","children":[{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial4-buffer/README.md","name":"README.md","display":"/beginner/tutorial4-buffer/README.md","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial4-buffer/figures.svg","name":"figures.svg","display":"/beginner/tutorial4-buffer/figures.svg","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial4-buffer/gradient.png","name":"gradient.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial4-buffer/gradient.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial4-buffer/indexed-pentagon.png","name":"indexed-pentagon.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial4-buffer/indexed-pentagon.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial4-buffer/pentagon.png","name":"pentagon.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial4-buffer/pentagon.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial4-buffer/triangle.png","name":"triangle.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial4-buffer/triangle.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial4-buffer/vb_desc.png","name":"vb_desc.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial4-buffer/vb_desc.png","type":"file"}]},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial5-textures","name":"tutorial5-textures","display":"/beginner/tutorial5-textures","type":"folder","children":[{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial5-textures/README.md","name":"README.md","display":"/beginner/tutorial5-textures/README.md","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial5-textures/address_mode.png","name":"address_mode.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial5-textures/address_mode.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial5-textures/address_mode.xcf","name":"address_mode.xcf","display":"/beginner/tutorial5-textures/address_mode.xcf","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial5-textures/happy-tree-uv-coords.png","name":"happy-tree-uv-coords.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial5-textures/happy-tree-uv-coords.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial5-textures/happy-tree-uv-coords.xcf","name":"happy-tree-uv-coords.xcf","display":"/beginner/tutorial5-textures/happy-tree-uv-coords.xcf","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial5-textures/happy-tree.png","name":"happy-tree.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial5-textures/happy-tree.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial5-textures/happy-tree.xcf","name":"happy-tree.xcf","display":"/beginner/tutorial5-textures/happy-tree.xcf","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial5-textures/rightside-up.png","name":"rightside-up.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial5-textures/rightside-up.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial5-textures/upside-down.png","name":"upside-down.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial5-textures/upside-down.png","type":"file"}]},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial6-uniforms","name":"tutorial6-uniforms","display":"/beginner/tutorial6-uniforms","type":"folder","children":[{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial6-uniforms/README.md","name":"README.md","display":"/beginner/tutorial6-uniforms/README.md","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial6-uniforms/newtranspipe.png","name":"newtranspipe.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial6-uniforms/newtranspipe.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial6-uniforms/static-tree.png","name":"static-tree.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial6-uniforms/static-tree.png","type":"file"}]},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial7-instancing","name":"tutorial7-instancing","display":"/beginner/tutorial7-instancing","type":"folder","children":[{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial7-instancing/README.md","name":"README.md","display":"/beginner/tutorial7-instancing/README.md","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial7-instancing/forest.png","name":"forest.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial7-instancing/forest.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial7-instancing/instance_texture.png","name":"instance_texture.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial7-instancing/instance_texture.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial7-instancing/instance_texture_scaled.png","name":"instance_texture_scaled.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial7-instancing/instance_texture_scaled.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial7-instancing/instance_texture_scaled.xcf","name":"instance_texture_scaled.xcf","display":"/beginner/tutorial7-instancing/instance_texture_scaled.xcf","type":"file"}]},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial8-depth","name":"tutorial8-depth","display":"/beginner/tutorial8-depth","type":"folder","children":[{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial8-depth/README.md","name":"README.md","display":"/beginner/tutorial8-depth/README.md","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial8-depth/forest.xcf","name":"forest.xcf","display":"/beginner/tutorial8-depth/forest.xcf","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial8-depth/forest_fixed.png","name":"forest_fixed.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial8-depth/forest_fixed.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial8-depth/forest_with_zoom.png","name":"forest_with_zoom.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial8-depth/forest_with_zoom.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial8-depth/forest_with_zoom.xcf","name":"forest_with_zoom.xcf","display":"/beginner/tutorial8-depth/forest_with_zoom.xcf","type":"file"}]},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial9-models","name":"tutorial9-models","display":"/beginner/tutorial9-models","type":"folder","children":[{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial9-models/README.md","name":"README.md","display":"/beginner/tutorial9-models/README.md","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial9-models/cube-diffuse.jpg","name":"cube-diffuse.jpg","display":"/beginner/tutorial9-models/cube-diffuse.jpg","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial9-models/cubes-correct.png","name":"cubes-correct.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial9-models/cubes-correct.png","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//beginner/tutorial9-models/cubes.png","name":"cubes.png","display":"/beginner/tutorial9-models/cubes.png","type":"file"}]}]},{"path":"src/articles//hello.md","name":"hello.md","display":"/hello.md","type":"file"},{"path":"src/articles//tree.json","name":"tree.json","display":"/tree.json","type":"file"}]}
```

I'm using this data to rewrite my tutorial/blog [sotrh.github.io/learn-wgpu](https://sotrh.github.io/learn-wgpu).

Comment: Webpack doesn't lint your code, you probably have `ESLint` or `TSLint` installed.

Comment: I've got a tslint.json file, so it's probably `TSLint`.

Comment: If you want to disable linting for semicolons entirely, you can add `"semicolon": [true, "never"]` as a rule to `tslint.json`.

Comment: That works for semicolons, but there are a lot of other linting errors that I'd have to change. I'd like to disable linting entirely for the JSON file when I'm importing it with Webpack, while maintaining the linting for regular files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your `tslint.json` to prevent linting of all json files recursively in your project:

```
{
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "*.json",
      "**/*.json"
    ]
  }
}
```

See [this](https://github.com/google/gts/issues/172#issuecomment-433321584) GitHub issue for more information.